# Merging certain parts of a list together, depending on an item in the list - Python

Tags: python, list, merge, slice

I would like to merge certain parts of a list together depending on whether a comma is present. If I user inputs: `"1231,fdkgjdkfj45,294d"`, I would like it to be converted to `["1231", "45", "294"]`. I am able to delete everything in the list that isn't a number (using list comprehension) but I would like the program to recognize where a comma is, then merge the items in the list prior to the comma together (up until the previous comma).

I understand I haven't worded this amazingly but I think you should be able to understand what I mean.

The steps I feel are necessary are as follow:

1. Delete everything in the list that isn't a number or a comma (Done this, using another list and list comprehension)
2. Check if there are any commas next to each other and then delete duplicates. (I should be able to do this rather easily)
3. Use a "for" loop to check the positions in the list, and when finding a comma, merge all items in the list prior to this comma, and up until the previous comma, together. (This is what I cannot do)

Any responses would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where is your code, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: you need to show us what you try before !

Comment: The hate is strong. 
I'm new here, this is my second post. I know what to do next tho'

Comment: there is no hate , all is for yourself ,and SO is a place for learning , peoples here are not for just solve the problems , but for learning together !

Comment: Fair enough, I enjoy learning new tricks for Python like those below. Cheers for the advice! :)

Comment: You probably got downvotes because you didn't show us your code. It's great that you outlined the steps you feel are necessary, but you'll get a more positive response here in future if you show us actual code that we can help you fix. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for that comment, that's help a newbie out like me a great deal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `split` the list on the `','` character, then iterate over each sublist and `join` the characters that are digits.

```
>>> s = "1231,fdkgjdkfj45,294d"
>>> [''.join(i for i in chunk if i.isdigit()) for chunk in s.split(',')]
['1231', '45', '294']
```

If you are not yet familiar with list comprehensions (which is what is shown above) here is a more step-by-step solution that is approximately equivalent

```
numList = []
for chunk in s.split(','):
    digits = []
    for char in chunk:
        if char.isdigit():
            digits.append(char)
    numList.append(''.join(digits))

>>> numList
['1231', '45', '294']
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is more on my level in terms of not having to implement another module.

Comment: @Shaney96: Regular Expressions (regex) are powerful, and _definitely_ worth learning about. Most scripting languages have some form of regex support, although there are some variations in the syntax, but once you've got the hang of them in one language, you'll be able to use them in others. However, I feel that using a regex is probably overkill for your question, and I'd tend to use the approach used in Cyber's answer.

Comment: I'll agree to that one, I'm currently doing my A2 level computing course and obviously still learning a lot about this language and taking a lot in :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need regex..

```
>>> import re
>>> str_="1231,fdkgjdkfj45,294d"
>>> re.findall(r'[0-9]+',str_)  #[0-9] tells regex to look for digits only while + tells to look for one or more of them
['1231', '45', '294']
```

Comment: its better to use `re.split()` than `findall()` also you shouldn't answer to a homework like question !

Comment: Cheers for this, I've not heard of this module before and this worked a charm, I'll do some research into regex so I understand how it works.

Comment: And this isn't a homework question, I'm just stuck at a part in my game I'm creating, which is a Towers of Hanoi game in Tkinter